# Fatal Error in uploading to google DOcs using Zend_GData

Tags: php, zend-framework, google-docs

Hi guys I'm trying the code samples from [zend frameworks](http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/trunk/demos/Zend/Gdata/Docs.php) site on how to upload a document to google docs but I keep getting this error.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Zend_Gdata_App_HttpException' with message 'Expected response code 200, got 415
Content-Type application/x-www-form-urlencoded is not a valid input type.' in C:\...\Zend\Gdata\App.php:700
```

It can't be an unlisted type as I tried to upload even a .txt file - whats happening here - I've googled everywhere for an answer and landed nowhere - please help :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the HTTP status code - `415 Unsupported Media Type`. It seems that the code is out of date (are you on 1.10?). Here's the [list of data you can upload](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/faq.html#WhatKindOfFilesCanIUpload) from Google. Suggested fix is to check this list exists in `Zend/library/Zend/Gdata/Docs.php`:

```
private static $SUPPORTED_FILETYPES = array( 
      'CSV'=>'text/csv', 
      'DOC'=>'application/msword', 
      'ODS'=>'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet', 
      'ODT'=>'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text', 
      'RTF'=>'application/rtf', 
      'SXW'=>'application/vnd.sun.xml.writer', 
      'TXT'=>'text/plain', 
      'XLS'=>'application/vnd.ms-excel');
```

Google groups posting [here](http://groups.google.com/group/Google-Docs-Data-APIs/browse_thread/thread/75c40d43919f965b).

Answer (score 1):

The probem is the mimetype ("extension type that can't be identified ) Just Go to your  library folder look Zend/Gdata/Docs.php file on line 244

insert this :

> // Set the mime type of the data.
>           if ($mimeType === null) {   $filenameParts = explode('.',
>   $slugHeader); // <-- now slugheader
>   equals myfilename.txt   $fileExtension
>   = end($filenameParts);   $mimeType = self::lookupMimeType($fileExtension);
>     }

instead of this :

> // Set the mime type of the data.
>           if ($mimeType === null) {
>             $filenameParts = explode('.', $fileLocation);
>             $fileExtension = end($filenameParts);
>             $mimeType = self::lookupMimeType($fileExtension);
>           }
>   and now everything is gonna be ok. ;)
>    Enjoy it.